# Facing some errors when integrating angular 8 application with Azure SSO

Tags: angular, azure, node-modules, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have integrated my angular 8 application with azure SSO as there are 2 ways to integrate for sign-in with popup or redirect() I am not facing any issue with popup but when I try to integrate with redirect I am getting below error I tried searching for similar issue online to find solution but couldn't find any. This has been bugging me since past couple days. It would be really helpful if anyone can suggestion some solution for these errors to be fixed.
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD9U2.png)    [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr1f9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your application URI and redirect URI is the same in Azure or not. And add your  `redirect URI` in your code as in azure after copy from here.
[image]

Please refer the below links for more information:

.[Configure SSO in Angular| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code) .

. [Setup Angular Application To Use Azure AD Authentication](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setup-angular-application-to-use-azure-ad-authentication/) .

.[Angular MSAL login example| Git-Hub](https://github.com/tamani-coding/angular-msal-login-example) .